# bash insert backslash for every slash in string

Tags: bash, sed, string, escape-characters

I have a string that is a path:

```
/tmp/something
```

I need to escape the forward slashes with backslashes:

```
\/tmp\/something
```

How can I do this? Maybe `sed`?

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with Bash's own variable manipulation methods (parameter expansion), though the syntax is fairly monstrous:

```
$ string='/tmp/something'
$ escapedstring="${string//\//\\\/}"
$ printf '%s\n' "$escapedstring"     
\/tmp\/something
```

To explain this further, in bash `${var//xxx/yyy}` means "take variable `var` and replace all occurrences of `xxx` with `yyy`." In this case, you need to escape the slashes in specifying the substituend and substitute; the former is `\/` for a single forward slash and latter is `\\\/` for a backslash plus forward slash, so you end up with the ridiculous looking `${string//\//\\\/}`.

Remember not to use `echo` to display its contents as depending on the implementation or environment, `echo` may do it's own processing of backslash characters.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is the right direction! Follow a tutorial like https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1 ; the very basic method is

```bsh
echo $string | sed 's;old;replacement;g'
```

where `s` is the command, i.e. "search and replace", `g` is the flag that means "repeat on each line until you're done", `old` is what you want to replace (`/` in your case) and `replacement` is what you want to replace it with. (You might need to escape the backslash, so `\\/`.)

Have fun!

Comment: `sed` processes each line as default, `g` flag says: repeat on each match on a line until end of line. If not used `sed` stop searching on first match on a line, and skip to next line.

Comment: @schweik exactly what a I meant with *repeat on each line* (should probably have used "within")

Comment: No problem, I wrote it not to you but to any newbie :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something along these lines.

```bsh
# let
str='/tmp/something'
str_esc=$(printf '%s\n' "$str" | sed 's:/:\\&:g')
```